# ASP.NET MVC3 how to wait for async call back and return result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback

**Background:**

I'm working on Cache warmup functionality to increase the performance on ASP.NET MVC Web by pre-loading the object in Cache before it's been requested.

I'm using Azure In-Role cache, which provided AddItemLevelCallback function when Cache is updated/removed/added etc. I've shared the code logic below.

Problem:

The AddItemLevelCallback on NotifyOnceCacheIsUpdated shown in the code snippet below doesn't get invoked straight away until Item is added/updated. The request will need to wait. But the problem is the the  AddItemLevelCallback is async and KickOffWarmUpCache on DAL may return before the actual item is added/updated.

What would be the elegant way to handle this scenario where KickOffWarmUpCache only returns the result to the caller only after AddItemLevelCallback is triggered.

Technology: MVC3, .NET Framework 4.5

Code Sample:

CONTROLLER

```
 public void WarmUpCache(string id)
 {
    var userInfo = BLL.KickOffWarmUpCache(string id);
 }
```

BLL

```
public UserInfo KickOffWarmUpCache(string id)
{
    return DAL.KickOffWarmUpCache(string id)
}
```

DAL

```
public UserInfo KickOffWarmUpCache(string id)
{
    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
    //If Status = Progress
    if (cache.Get(id).Status == "Progress")
    {
        NotifyOnceCacheIsUpdated(id,(result)=>
        {
            userInfo=result.userInfo;
        });
    }else{
           userInfo=Cache.Get(id);
     }

      //This needs to wait for until callback is triggered and userInfo is populated
      return userInfo;
}
```

UTIL

```
public void NotifyOnceCacheIsUpdated(string cacheKey, Action<T> callback)
 {
    DataCacheOperations allCacheOperations = DataCacheOperations.ReplaceItem | DataCacheOperations.AddItem ;
    _ndItemLvlAllOps = cache.AddItemLevelCallback(cacheKey, allCacheOperations,
                     (CacheName, cacheRegion, cacheKey, itemVersion, OperationId, nd) =>
                        {
                            cachedData = cache.Get(cacheKey);
                            callback(cachedData);
                        });
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered just using `Task` `async`?

Comment: Yes but won't solve given problem I.e. wait and return result given by Callback function

Comment: ...Wait and Return Result is kind of the WHOLE IDEA of `Task` `async`. Or is your problem that your current function is not in a TPL friendly signature? If this is the case, you should wrap up the logic in a `TaskCompletionSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Task<UserInfo> KickOffWarmUpCache(string id)
{

    //If Status = Progress
    if (cache.Get(id).Status == "Progress")
    {
        var ret = new TaskCompletionSource<UserInfo>();
        NotifyOnceCacheIsUpdated(id,(result)=>
        {
            //complete the task.
            ret.SetResult(result.userInfo);
        });
        //return a Task...which the SetResult will complete.
        return ret.Task;
    }

    //Return a result synchronously
    return Task.FromResult(Cache.Get(id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @aron, are you able to clarify what's the diff between return ret.Task vs. Task.FromResult(new UserInfo()). Does later returns null object?

Comment: Also I've added else { userInfo=cache.Get(id);}.

Comment: `Task.FromResult` is useful for returning a Task with an already completed result. Typically you use it when you can synchronously generate the result. Whilst `TaskCompletionSource.Task` returns a `Task` that hasn't been completed yet, and can be completed using `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult` by another thread.